# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory when trying to execute the jar

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, slf4j-api

When I try to do java -jar app.jar I get this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at tao.qaflash.GUI.<clinit>(GUI.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$156(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

My environment is: Java 1.8.0_92, Gradle 2.16, Eclipse Mars 4.5.0, Java FX.
Also I have googled this error and I have tried everything from there , but with no success. I tried to add to the build.gradle as dependencies slfj-simple, log4j, logback-classic, slf4j-jdk14,junit,vaadin-slf4j-jdk14 but the error kept appearing.

When I run the application from Eclipse, everything works fine, the logs are written, only when I try to run the jar from command line, I get this ClassNotFoundException.

build.gradle looks like :

```
dependencies {
  compile 'net.sf.staf:jstaf:3.4.4'

  // SLF4J API module which will be used for logging
  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

  // Log4J2 logging framework including the binding module to slf4j
  compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.5'
  compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5'
  compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.+"
  testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-junit:4.0.+"
}
```

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback :-)

Comment: For anyone else reading: Are you running your file.jar with same JDK version, as you compiled it ? (As a first step, I recommend to use same JDK, not even JRE of same version.) Just to exclude possible source of error. This fixed my problem with same symptoms :)
Use this sample line to point to any JVM: 
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe"   -jar  
 d:\Path\To\Your\File.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: the **classpath** that you are using when trying to **execute** your JAR file does *not* contain the required sl4j logger library.

That is all there is to this. This is **not** about your build setup - it is about the *setup* that gets used when you run `java` on the command line!

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for further reading.

Comment: I have tried to set the classpath from the command line and also I got the same error:

Comment: java -jar app.jar  -classpath C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.21\139535a69a4239db087de9bab0bee568bf8e0b70\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar

Comment: That is *AP*I jar. I wouldnt be surprised if slf4j also has some **implementation** jar. In other words: one jar might not do!

Answer (score 1):

I have unzipped the zip file that was created in the dist folder and it works :) because in the lib folder there was the sl4j-api.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need slf4j at runtime as well. Have a look at the [gradle dependency configuration options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations)

Comment: But there is already in the depedency:  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21' and i still got the error ....